# How to submit form in Modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem when I submit form, this page is not direct to next PHP page but go to main page.

> (entry_pbd.php)

This my modal code.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- body modal -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="entry_pbd.php" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="form-save">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="price1">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#billto" href="#collapse1" id="billto" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                                    <b>Price 1 </b></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <label> Minimum Order Quantity (MOQ)</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Minimum Order Quantity" id="moq_1" name="moq_1" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> <br></br>
                                <label>Unit Price</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Unit Price" id="up_1" name="up_1" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="modal-footer">                               
        <button style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> Submit</button>
        <button style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-warning" type="reset"> Reset</button>
        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

This is entry_pdb.php sample code

```
<?php

$id_form = $_POST['id_form'];
$id_pur = $_POST['id_purchase'];
$moq_1 = $_POST['moq_1'];$up_1 = $_POST['up_1'];

if ($moq_1 != "")
{
$sql = "insert into pbd_pur values ('1','$id_form','$moq_1','$up_1')";
$hasil = mysqli_query($connect2,$sql);  
}
echo $sql;
$link = "update_p.php?id=".$id_pur;
//echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$link.'">';
?>
```

I just want to look message (error or success) in entry_pdb.php after submit form in modal.

Comment: You are submitting your form to `entry_pbd.php`  here `<form action="entry_pbd.php" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="form-save">` what php code is  inside **entry_pbb.php**

Comment: There's no redirection code here, can you show `entry_pbd.php` (in your question)?

Comment: @danish-khan-I I have been update my question...

Comment: @kerbholz I have been update my question

Comment: where is your form submit button? Form submitting is usually trigger by pressing a `<input type="button" />`

Comment: @RaymondM, I have been update the code.

Comment: At the moment it isn't redirecting because you commented out the line which causes. But also you can issue a location header instead of using a meta tag, it will likely cause the redirect more quickly. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php/

Comment: @ADyson, can you explain your answer ?

Comment: In `//echo '<META...` - the `//` turns the line into a comment instead of code, so it doesn't get executed. But there's a better way to write a redirect anyway...see the link I gave you

Comment: @ADyson that's why, I'm doing `//echo`. Because I just want to look that from submit modal page and then page direct to entry_pbd.php

Comment: Eh? Do you know what a comment is? Remove the `//` and try again. Or switch to using a location header, as per that link I have you (and the answer below)

Answer (score 1):

write redirection code in your php file just below record saving code. like

Either

```
header("Location: http://www.redirect.to.url.com/"); // pass your file path ,where you want to navigate
```

Or (if you are using cakePHP)

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'my_action'));  // if you are using cake php
```

Comment: can you explain that ?

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar you are using core php code. for redirection purpose there is a inbuilt function header in php . please read this docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php